# How to delete Google Tag Manager code from Neve Theme (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-tag-manager

My web site's ( [MY BGMI](https://mybgmi.com/) ) loading time is increasing due to the Google Tag Manager Code. Then I have disconnected the google tag manager from Google Site Kit plugin. But the GTM code is still here in my theme. I have tried to find the GTM code in theme file editor but I didn't find any code in theme file.

I tried to delete it from theme file but I didn't find the GTM code there. Now, I am clueless and I need help.

Comment: Why do you think you're loading GTM? You're loading gtag, not GTM. You're sending events into one UA and two GA4 accounts. But they shouldn't be relevant to your loading time issues. And GTM, too, generally, has little to no influence on site performance

Answer (score 0):

Use a website speed tool to identify the specific GTM code slowing down your site. If it persists after disconnecting from Google Site Kit, check for inline scripts, widgets, or a caching issue. Clear cache, disable caching plugins temporarily, and inspect your theme's header/footer directly in WordPress editor. If unsuccessful, consider seeking professional assistance or contacting your theme's support for guidance.